# Missing arguments for a NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, posix

I'm writing a NodeJS app that accepts command-line arguments. To parse the options, I'm using a Node package called [Commander](https://www.npmjs.org/package/commander). There's one option (-f / --fileName) that I want to check. Here's what different inputs produce:

`nodeapp --fileName sampleFile` results in `program.fileName="sampleFile"`

`nodeapp --fileName` results in `program.fileName=undefined`

`nodeapp" results` results in `program.fileName=undefined`

I want `nodeapp --fileName` to throw a "Please specify a file name" error, but I want `nodeapp` to work fine.

Is there any standard that specifies how to deal with missing parameters, or a best-practice that I should follow?

In other words, if an option requires a parameter, and the parameter is not provided, should it be treated as an error case, or should the option be ignored?

Comment: i guess that depends on the option level of importance. if your option can fallback to a default behavior then you shouldn't bug the user with a message, if your option is needed the you can ask for input. if  missing the option implies a security risk then you just crash the program and possibly avoid restarting it all depends on your app and the type of option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use commander occasionally.  If it is a program-critical input I usually just check for it and exit the program with a message if it doesn't exist.

```
if(!argv.port) {
    console.log('Please provide a port number.');
    process.exit(0);
}
```

If it is not critical I usually pull it out into its own variable like:

```
var host = (argv.host) ? argv.host : '127.0.0.1';
```

This way it will default to my local machine if I don't pass it any host info.

Answer (score 0):

The [NodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) suggests that you either set `exitCode` to a non-zero value, or throw an uncaught error.

It specifically says that you should not use `process.exit` in the case where a condition is not met.

Here's the text of the documentation for `process.exit`:

> Calling process.exit() will force the process to exit as quickly as
>   possible even if there are still asynchronous operations pending that
>   have not yet completed fully, including I/O operations to
>   process.stdout and process.stderr.
>
> In most situations, it is not actually necessary to call
>   process.exit() explicitly. The Node.js process will exit on its own if
>   there is no additional work pending in the event loop. The
>   process.exitCode property can be set to tell the process which exit
>   code to use when the process exits gracefully.
>
> For instance, the following example illustrates a misuse of the
>   process.exit() method that could lead to data printed to stdout being
>   truncated and lost:
>
> ```
> // This is an example of what *not* to do: 
> if (someConditionNotMet()) {   
>   printUsageToStdout();   
>   process.exit(1); 
> }
> ```
>
> The reason this is
>   problematic is because writes to process.stdout in Node.js are
>   sometimes asynchronous and may occur over multiple ticks of the
>   Node.js event loop. Calling process.exit(), however, forces the
>   process to exit before those additional writes to stdout can be
>   performed.
>
> Rather than calling process.exit() directly, the code should set the
>   process.exitCode and allow the process to exit naturally by avoiding
>   scheduling any additional work for the event loop:
>
> ```
> // How to properly set the exit code while letting the process exit gracefully. 
> if (someConditionNotMet()) {
>   printUsageToStdout();  
>   process.exitCode = 1; 
> }
> ```
>
> If it is necessary to terminate the Node.js
>   process due to an error condition, throwing an uncaught error and
>   allowing the process to terminate accordingly is safer than calling
>   process.exit().